# Spring 4 @Configuration order for setting up JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jersey-2.0

I had a working Jersey 2.2 applisaction with Spring 4 in which I was using Eclipselink as JPA implementation.

The application config calss looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(value = "com.nws.vedica", lazyInit = true)
@PropertySource({"classpath:swagger.properties", "classpath:vedica.properties"})
@ApplicationPath("/api")

public class VedicaConfig extends ResourceConfig {

public VedicaConfig() {
    packages("com.nws.vedica");
    property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true);
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    register(JacksonFeature.class);
    register(ValidationFeature.class);
    register(ValidationConfigurationContextResolver.class);
    register(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class);

    register(ApiListingResource.class);
    register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
}
}
```

The JPA configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

private Map<String, String> properties;

@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbConnectionURL;

@Value("${db.user}")
private String dbUser;

@Value("${db.pass}")
private String dbPassword;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbConnectionURL);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPassword);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.target-database", "PostgreSQL");
    properties.put("eclipselink.cache.shared.default", "true");
    properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation", "none");
    properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level.sql", "fine");
    properties.put("eclipselink.logging.parameters", "true");
    properties.put("eclipselink.deploy-on-startup", "true");
    properties.put("eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode", "database");
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransMan(){
    JpaTransactionManager jtManager = new JpaTransactionManager(
            getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
    return jtManager;
}

@Bean
public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean lemfb = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lemfb.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    lemfb.setPersistenceUnitName(Vedantas.PU_NAME);
    lemfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.class);
    return lemfb;
}
}
```

Now, this works well. On startup, application config class is being loaded FIRST so "PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" gets registered and I can use @Value(...) annotations in jpa config class which gets loaded as SECOND.

Today I have decided that I'll replace Eclipselink with Hibernate because of it's auditing abilities.

To pom.xml I have added:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

and have changed jpa config class to:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JPAConfig {

private Map<String, String> properties;

@Value("${db.url}")
private String dbConnectionURL;

@Value("${db.user}")
private String dbUser;

@Value("${db.pass}")
private String dbPassword;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", dbConnectionURL);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", dbUser);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", dbPassword);
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.target-database", "PostgreSQL");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);

    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.nws.vedica.model"});
    em.setPersistenceUnitName(Vedantas.PU_NAME);

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

    return em;
}
}
```

Now, to my surprise, load/execution order of application config and jpa config classes has swapped so jpa config is being loaded FIRST and then application config SECONDLY which causes "PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" not being registered at jpa config class load time, so @value annotations are not working!

I am really interested in knowing why is that so? Why has the execution order swapped?

I know I can trick it by not declaring jpa config calass as @Configuration and just register it as a bean in application config class like:

```
    @Bean
    public JPAConfig setUpJpaHibernate() {
        return new JPAConfig();
    }
```

But still, I would like to know, what is happening here?

Comment: There is no information about how the Spring application is bootstrapped? Typically spring reads all the configurations, builds a dependency tree and instantiates the leaf nodes first. If there is no reference between your two configurations there is nothing to tell Spring which order it should instantiate them in (so you should consider the order random). There are special rules for ProperyConfiguration, for instance if you have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` the been definition must be a static method. So I would always put @PropertySource in the bootstrapped configuration.

Comment: well basically, you didn't answer my question nor provided solution. I have two pieces of code that behaves differently. I need to make sure class that extends RecourceConfig loads first, because this is where app config takes place.

Comment: Normally I would just debug the Spring code to figure out why this happens. For some reason the dependency resolution in Spring causes your `JPAConfig` to be processed before the Config that extends `ResourceConfig`, normally this would be due to a dependency between the two, or if they are both leaf-configurations the order is 'random'. Personally I'm more curious about which problem Jersey solves, that Spring MVC does not, and why the auditing in EclipseLink is not good enough?

Answer (score 0):

the reason that the order changed was introduction of `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` bean into JPAConfig class.

```
@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

Moving this to the VedicaConfig class solves the problem for me.